# mysqli limits yield more results than the limit

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this to fetch results from database.

```
$from=$to; ////limit from
$to=$from+5; ////limit to
$search_query="SELECT * FROM `user_info_secondary` WHERE `city`='$query' LIMIT $from,$to"
```

When i set `$to=0;` the search yields exactly 5 results but when i set to `$to=5,10,15....` its shows me 6 results why is that?

```
$from=$to;
$to=$from+5;
$search_query="SELECT * FROM `user_info_secondary` WHERE `city`='$query' LIMIT $from,$to";
$do_search=  mysqli_query($connection, $search_query);
$number_of_results= mysqli_num_rows($do_search);
while($number_of_results>0)
{
       $get_result_details= mysqli_fetch_array($do_search);
       $search_result_details= $get_result_details['username'];
       echo $search_result_details;
       --$number_of_results;
}
```

Comment: It's not `from, to`, it's `offset, count`.

Comment: im sorry that is what i meant im really new at this and not aware of all the terminology so what is the problem with that code?

Comment: Whenever I see people that use `mysqli_query()` are still passing in unescaped variables, I die inside a little.

Comment: I'm really sorry i don't even know what unescaped variables means I'm really new at this will try to read and improve myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barmar said, it's not `from`, `to` - its `offset`, `count`

`offset` of 5 means item # 4 is where it starts

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and `count` of 10 results in:

```
0, 1, 2, 3 [START HERE] -> 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 //(because 0 is part of that count so 9 is last).
```

aka **6 items**

`offset` 0 means you start at item # 0 and `count` of 5 results in

```
[START HERE] -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

aka **5 items**

### Just do this to fix it:

```
$from = ##;  // Where ## is the number you choose
$to = ($from > 0) ? $from + 4 : $from + 5;
```

Comment: didn't fix it when i tried this the same way a couple of days ago it worked fine.

Comment: figured it my self understood what offset and count really means